# ¿Como leer un archivo CSV en Python y extraer el maximo y el minimo valor por minuto?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

He utilizado este código para extraer los datos de un archivo CSV, filtrarlos y hasta organizarlos por minuto, pero me gustaría su ayuda para crear un ciclo que me permita actualizar la información por minuto, determinando el máximo y el mínimo valor.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

datos = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/TECNOLOGIA/datos.csv', names=['LocalTime', 'Message', 'MarketTime', 'Symbol', 'Type', 'Price', 'Size', 'Source','Condition','Tick','Mmid','SubMarketId','Date'], usecols=['Type','MarketTime','Price'],index_col='Type')

df=pd.DataFrame(datos)
df=(df.loc['Type=0'])
"""Con el siguiente codigo se eliminan las letras de MarketTime y Price"""

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['MarketTime']=df['MarketTime'].str.extract('((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d)')
df2['Price']=df['Price'].str.extract('(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')

"""Con el siguiente codigo se agrupa por minutos"""

df2['MarketTime']=pd.DatetimeIndex(df2['MarketTime'])
df2.set_index(keys='MarketTime', inplace=True)
inicio=datetime.time(11,18)
fin=datetime.time(11,19)
print(df2[['Price']].between_time(inicio,fin))
```

Lo que no he podido es hacer que esto sea un bucle que me permita determinar el valor más alto y el más bajo de cada minuto del archivo. Este archivo se está actualizando permanentemente por ello, es importante que el código tome la información nueva.

El código genera esta salida:

[image: Salida del script en Python]

Comment: En un bucle en tiempo real? ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede hacer de varias formas. Una forma rápida es creando un bucle infinito con la instrucción "**while True**" y anidando todo el código dentro de dicho while. Para que se ejecute cada 1 minuto debes incluir al final del bucle la instrucción **time.sleep(60)**.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import time

while True:
   datos = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/TECNOLOGIA/datos.csv', names=['LocalTime', 'Message', 'MarketTime', 'Symbol', 'Type', 'Price', 'Size', 'Source','Condition','Tick','Mmid','SubMarketId','Date'], usecols=['Type','MarketTime','Price'],index_col='Type')
   #Incluye el resto de código...
   time.sleep(60)  # Espera 60 segundos
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte!!

Answer (score 0):

Primero deberias truncar el atributo `MarketTime` para que queden solo hasta los minutos de la siguiente forma

```
df['MarketTime'] = df['MarketTime'].values.astype('<M8[m]')
```

Luego usando la funcion la funcion max y min hallarias los valores correspondientes agrupando por MarketTime, seria algo asi :

```
df.groupby('MarketTime').agg({'max':np.max,'min':np.min})['Price']
```

Esto te devolveria un dataFrame con `MarketTime`, **max** y **min** como columnas